# Issue with CALDB -- NICER data processing

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I've been working on processing NICER data on my ubuntu, and I've been having some issues with CALDB. I'm trying to work with the remote access CALDB ([1](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/heasarc/caldb/caldb_remote_access.html)) but can't seem to get it to work. Here's the string of errors that come up after I've executed

*heainit*

*nicerl2 indir=/home/[user]/w3browse-319801/1050360102 clobber = yes*

in terminal.

Error message:

```
ERROR: CALDB MPU_GAIN file query failed at /home/[user]/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/bin/nicerpi line 222.
Dumping CFITSIO error stack:
--------------------------------------------------
ERROR ftp_status wants 331  but got 550
Server is requesting SSL, will switch to ftps (ftp_file_exist)
ERROR: This CFITSIO build was not compiled with the libcurl library package
and therefore it cannot perform HTTPS or FTPS connections.
Unable to read ftps file into memory (ftps_open)
failed to find or open the following file: (ffopen)
ftp://legacy.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/nicer/xti/caldb.indx
CFITSIO error stack dump complete.
Fail to select CALDB file with the given criteria (at HDgtcalf.c: 142)
Unable to open CALDB index file (at HDgtcalf.c: 202)
CFITSIO ERROR FILE_NOT_OPENED: could not open the named file
Task nicerpi 1.24 terminating with status 104
ERROR: fast event calibration failed at /home/[user]/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/bin/nimpucal line 206.
Task nimpucal 1.8 terminating with status -1
Warning: something's wrong at /home/[user]/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/bin/nimpucal line 33.
ERROR: MPU0 calibration failed at /home/[user]/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/bin/nicercal line 291.
Task nicercal 1.7 terminating with status -1
ERROR: task nicercal failed at /home/[user]/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/bin/nicerl2 line 299.
Task nicerl2 1.12 terminating with status -1
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was cfitsio could not open files remotely because I installed heasoft without installing libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the HEASARC no longer support ftp so that you need to point your $CALDB environment variable to

https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/caldb

instead of

ftp://legacy.gsfc.nasa.gov/caldb